# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: and text input

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to enter in text input in this 'CC' field located at:

https://ggbs.tarim.gov.tr/cis/servlet/StartCISPage?PAGEURL=/FSIS/ggbs.takviyeGidaSorgu.html&POPUPTITLE=AnaMenu

using python and selenium. It seems to be wrapped in a frame or two, and I'm unable to locate the element using selenium. Code is below. What am I doing wrong?

````
time.sleep(15)
driver.switch_to.frame('SCPIFRAMEMozilla') #('SCPFRAMEBUFFER')
captcha=driver.find_element_by_name('CC')```
````

Comment: Where is that CC field in the web page ?

Comment: It's on the top for the captcha input

Comment: yeah I figured that out, Check out the below solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the below code : I have included `explicit Wait` :

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://ggbs.tarim.gov.tr/cis/servlet/StartCISPage?PAGEURL=/FSIS/ggbs.takviyeGidaSorgu.html&POPUPTITLE=AnaMenu")
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe.SCPIFRAMEMozilla")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.FIELDInputEdit"))).send_keys("Some value")
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try xpath instead of name ;

```
captcha = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")
```

i looked on the site and xpath is ==> //*[@id='F_11']

so it will be like this

```
captcha = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='F_11']")
```